# Laravel 5 Multi-Tenancy App with single database for octoberCMS

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, octobercms

I'm building an SaaS application with octoberCMS. Basically, I want our client to be able to point their domain to our name servers and effectively the application will load their website template (which will vary from client to client).

It will also allow our clients' members to login to their account through their website and load all of their personal details.

How I can do that with https://laravel-tenancy.com/ ?

Comment: Nice project but I don't understand what is the question.

Comment: How we can do that with https://laravel-tenancy.com/ ?

Comment: You can start reading the laravel-tenancy documentation and trying to implement your buisness logic with your code. After that if you have any specific coding problem you can always ask here.